# How to use jQuery(...).material_chip inside WordPress?

Tags: front-end, input

Although I have imported materialize.js (v1.0.0) inside my plugin in WordPress with

```
$pluginpath = dirname (plugin_dir_url( __DIR__  ));
$pluginpath = str_replace('\\','/',$pluginpath);
$thepath = $pluginpath . '/js_libs/materialize.js';
wp_enqueue_script('wpunity_materialize_jslib', $thepath);
```

and in my main function

```
wp_register_script( 'wpunity_materialize_jslib', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js_libs/materialize.js', null, null, false);
```

I keep getting

jQuery(...).material_chip is not a function

for this code

```
<div id="textarea-collaborators" class="chips-autocomplete"></div>

                    <script>
                        jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
                            jQuery('.chips-autocomplete').material_chip({
                                secondaryPlaceholder: 'Your collaborator email',
                                placeholder: 'Your collaborator email'
                            });
                        });
                    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

```
wp_enqueue_script('wpunity_materialize_jslib', $thepath);
```

has to be called last, after all other calls to enqueue scripts that invoke jQuery.

SOLVED